# Is it possible to extend a MetadataType class to add extra decorators to a field?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

c# supports using a MetadataType class for applying additional decorators to classes which you don't want to edit directly (perhaps they're generated classes from Entity Framework, for example)

As a trivial example:

```
//auto generated class definition
public partial class DataClass
{
    public string DisplayName {get;set;}
}

//apply a metadata definition
[MetadataType(typeof(DataClassMetadata))]
public partial class DataClass
{

}

//implement the metadata 
public class DataClassMetadata
{
  [Display(Name = "Display Name")]
  public string DisplayName {get;set;}
}
```

This is all fine and dandy, until you have a another custom decorator to add which relies on dependencies you don't want to add to your business layer. For example, MVC remote validation which requires references to the MVC libraries.

What I'd like to be able to do is add another layer of metadata in the web project without losing the metadata defined in the business layer.

I thought about using some kind of inheritance, perhaps something like:

```
public class RemoteDataClassModelMetadata : DataClassMetadata
{
    [Remote("DataDisplayNameIsValid", "Validation")]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

and then having a view model which used this metadata definition - but it seems this just hides the decorators on the base class. Making the class partial won't work because the duplicate members won't even compile.

The problem can be avoided by either adding all the MVC references to the business layer (but this means that non web applications that rely on the business layer must now take on a web dependency for no good reason) or by duplicating the decorators in the web project (but this seems like the kind of thing that will lead to curious bugs and odd behaviour later on a project where a new dev doesn't realize they are defined in two places).

Is there a way to combine decorators from different metadata classes for this kind of use case? (Or is there a better solution to this problem that I'm totally overlooking?)

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Comment: We've yet to really solve this issue neatly. Currently we just have to duplicate the original attributes from the metadata class on the ViewModel and remember to keep them in sync.